# Can't make blending work

Tags: c++, opengl, blending, freeimage

I have a 3 dimensional dataset where each value of the dataset is normalized to `[0, 1]`. I want to visualize this dataset by using texture, and blending.
However, it seems that I can't make it work.

Here is what I have done so far:

```
int main(){
    ...
    //building an image for each rectangular slice of data
    vector<Texture> myTextures;
    for (GLint rowIndex = 0; rowIndex < ROW_NUM; rowIndex++)
    {
        auto pathToImage = "images/row" + to_string(rowIndex) + FILE_EXT;
        FIBITMAP *img = FreeImage_Allocate(SLICE_DIMENSION, SLICE_NUM, 32); //32 = RGBA

        for (GLint depthIndex = 0; depthIndex < DEPTH_NUM; depthIndex++)
        {
            for (GLint colIndex = 0; colIndex < COL_NUM; colIndex++)
            {
                auto value = my3DData[depthIndex][rowIndex][colIndex];

                //transform tValue to a source color
                glm::vec4 source = transformValueToColor(value);

                //note that here I am also setting the opacity. 
                RGBQUAD linRgb = { source.b, source.g, source.r, source.a }; 
                FreeImage_SetPixelColor(img, colIndex, depthIndex, &linRgb);
            }
        }

        //Saving images. Saved images shows transparency. 
        FreeImage_Save(FIF_PNG, img, pathToImage.c_str());
        myTextures.push_back(Texture(pathToImage.c_str(), GL_TEXTURE0));
    }
    //create VAO, VBO, EBO for a unit quad.

    glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);
    glEnable(GL_BLEND);
    glBlendFunc(GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);

    //game loop
    while (!glfwWindowShouldClose(window))
    {
        ...
        for (int i = 0; i < myTextures.size(); i++)
        {
            GLint index = myTextures.size() - i - 1;
            myTextures[index].bind(); //does glActiveTexture(...), and glBindTexture(...);

            glm::mat4 model;

            //translate
            model = glm::translate(model, glm::vec3(0.0f, 0.0f, -index*0.003f));

            //scale
            model = glm::scale(model, glm::vec3(1.2f));

            glUniformMatrix4fv(glGetUniformLocation(ourShader.Program, "model"), 1, GL_FALSE, glm::value_ptr(model));

            glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLES, 6, GL_UNSIGNED_INT, 0);
        }
    }
}
```

`transformValueToColor`for transforming data value in `[0,1]` to color value:

```
//All inputs >=0.6 is transformed to highly transparent white color.
glm::vec4 transformValueToColor(GLclampf tValue)
{
    if (tValue >= 0.6f) {
        return glm::vec4(255, 255, 255, 10);
    }
    else {
        auto val = round(255 * tValue);
        auto valOp = round(255 * (1 - tValue));
        return glm::vec4(val, val, val, valOp);
    }    
}
```

My vertex shader:

```
#version 330 core

layout(location = 0) in vec3 position;
layout(location = 1) in vec2 texCoord;

out vec2 TexCoord;

uniform mat4 model;
uniform mat4 view;
uniform mat4 projection;

void main()
{
    gl_Position = projection * view * model * vec4(position, 1.0f);
    TexCoord = vec2(texCoord.s, 1-texCoord.t);
}
```

My fragment shader:

```
#version 330 core

in vec2 TexCoord;

out vec4 color; 

uniform sampler2D sliceTexture;

void main()
{
    vec4 texColor = texture(sliceTexture, TexCoord); 
    color = texColor;
}
```

I think this is the code needed for the blending to work. The images are generated correctly, and also applied as texture on the quads correctly. However, the quads on the front appears as completely opaque, though the generated images (even the one appearing at front) shows transparent area.

I am not sure where I am going wrong. Requesting your suggestions.

Thank you.

**Edit:** details of `Texture` class (only the parts relevant to loading `RGBA` image and creating `RGBA` texture from that):

```
int width, height, channelCount;
unsigned char* image = SOIL_load_image(pathToImage, &width, &height, &channelCount, SOIL_LOAD_RGBA);
...    
glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGBA, width, height, 0, GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, image);
```

**Edit2:** Added details of camera class. `Camera::getViewMatrix()` provides `view` matrix.

```
Camera::Camera(GLFWwindow* window, glm::vec3 position, glm::vec3 worldUpDirection, GLfloat yaw, GLfloat pitch)
    :mouseSensitivity(0.25f), fov(45.0f), cameraSpeed(1.0f)
{
    this->position = this->originalPosition = position;
    this->worldUpDirection = worldUpDirection;
    this->yaw = this->originalYaw = yaw;
    this->pitch = this->originalPitch = pitch;

    updateCameraVectors();
}

void Camera::updateCameraVectors()
{
    glm::mat4 yawPitchRotMat;

    yawPitchRotMat = glm::rotate(yawPitchRotMat, glm::radians(yaw), glm::vec3(0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f));       //y-ais as yaw axis
    yawPitchRotMat = glm::rotate(yawPitchRotMat, glm::radians(pitch), glm::vec3(1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f));     //x-axis as pitch axis

    frontDirection = glm::normalize(-glm::vec3(yawPitchRotMat[2].x, yawPitchRotMat[2].y, yawPitchRotMat[2].z));

    rightDirection = glm::normalize(glm::cross(frontDirection, worldUpDirection));
    upDirection = glm::normalize(glm::cross(rightDirection, frontDirection));
}

glm::mat4 Camera::getViewMatrix()
{
    return glm::lookAt(position, position + frontDirection, upDirection);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
myTextures.push_back(Texture(pathToImage.c_str(), GL_TEXTURE0));
```

This doesn't include any information about your `Texture` class and how it's parsing the image files. Even if the files themselves show transparency, it's possible that your texture loading code is discarding the alpha channel when you load the image.

```
model = glm::translate(model, glm::vec3(0.0f, 0.0f, -index*0.003f));
```

This makes it look as if you're rendering from front to back.  If you want to render transparent objects, on top of one another you need to use an algorithm for order independent transparency, or you need to render from back to front.

```
glBlendFunc(GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);
```

You may also want / need to use `glBlendFuncSeparate` so that the mixing of the alpha channel is done differently.  I'm not sure about this one though.

You may also want to consider simply populating a single GL_TEXTURE_3D object and rendering it as a cube, doing all the mixing in the fragment shader, rather than rendering a series of quads for each layer.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I have added the relevant details of `Texture` class in question. Also regarding ordering, I think I am drawing the furthest quad first and the nearest quad last, as I think `z`-value decreases the more you go in front direction. What do you suggest?

Comment: Most OpenGL setups I've seen have the Z value decreasing as you move forward.  How it's going to work for you depends on how you created your View matrix, but you don't show that either.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. Added the `Camera` class details for view matrix.